# How to selectively replace values on a matrix?

Tags: matrix

```
Matrix1 ={{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 4, 
3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1}, {3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 
2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 
6, 6, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 2, 
3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

I want to create a matrix2 with same dimensions as matrix1 but replace all values less than 5 with 0. Help.! Thanks

Comment: Have you looked up `/.` in the docs? This is really something you can answer easily after reading the docs…

Comment: `UnitStep[Matrix1 - 6]`

Comment: @belisarius: minimalistic and cool +1

Comment: `matrix2 = Threshold[matrix1,4]`

Comment: `UnitStep[matrix1 - 5]*matrix1` is equal to `Threshold[matrix1, 4]`, but distinct than `UnitStep[Matrix1 - 6]`

Answer (score 8):

Just to explain... (once upon a time I was also very new to this Mathematica syntax - and often confused). 
The mentioned "/." replaces all elements in an expression. In addition with "/;" you can add a condition when this replacement should be done. So the solution to your problem is something like

```
matrix1 /. x_ /; x < 5 -> 0
```

(do not use upper case names for your symbols, Mathematica uses ONLY uppercase for the first character, so it is a good idea to choose lowercase characters for the first letter in your identifiers). So this replaces every occurrence of x with "0" if x is less than 5.

Answer (score 1):

This will be much faster than using rule replacement...

```
Clip[matrix1, {5, Infinity}, {0, Infinity}]
```

*If* entries are integer, `Threshold[matrix1,4]` s/b faster, but will fail for non-integers...